# ssh gateway which can proxy to upstream servers based on user name?

Tags: ssh

Every user has a dedicated machine, but is not exposed to the outside world. The 'gateway' is the only system that is exposed.

The user has no idea of this setup. He just does
`ssh username@gateway` which should be equivalent to `ssh username@username.internal`.

Can we configure a gateway sshd with which we can achieve this? Each machine has a single user. So, there can't be any confusion in determining the upstream server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up

```
Match group proxyUsers
  ForceCommand /bin/connect_to_user_machine
```

and having `/bin/connect_to_user_machine`

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $USER@$USER.internal $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

will do the job

Comment: Can I also pass the arguments given to `ssh user@gateway` to ssh `user@user.internal`?

Comment: It would need some modification. See edited answer.

Comment: Is it possible to not have the user accounts on the gateway machine? i.e, I would like the upstream ssh server to do the auth (the ForceCommand would be unconditional).

Comment: I don't think so. Username is send as part of the authentication. You don't know what username is the user trying to use before.